# Sub-query Sales and inventory

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: Products, Inventory and Ingredients

```
Product Table    
ID[PK]        Name            Type
1         OrdinaryBurger     Burger
2         CheeseBurger       Burger
```

---

```
Inventory table
ID[PK]    Item_name    Stocks
100       Buns         5
101       Patties      5
103       Cheese       0
```

---

```
Ingredients table
ID[PK]      ProductID[FK]    InventoryID[FK]  Quantity
1001        1                  100            1
1002        1                  101            1
1003        2                  100            1
1004        2                  101            1
1005        2                  103            1
```

I want to write a query that can filter all the products to not display if the connected inventory stock is 0, for example this will not display Cheeseburger because the stock of cheese is 0. THanks

Comment: What does the 1 for quantity mean? It's the not the amount, as that would be 5.

Comment: the 1 in quantity means the number of item(s) will be applied on the product for example in ordinary burger you need 1 patty, 1 Buns

Comment: FWIW, I think you could have held out for a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return only products that have at least enough ingredients to make.

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID NOT IN (
    SELECT i.ProductID
    FROM Ingredients i
    JOIN Inventory iv ON i.InventoryID = iv.InventoryId
    GROUP BY i.ProductID, i.InventoryId
    HAVING SUM(iv.Stocks) < SUM(i.Quantity)
)
```

Comment: The join to `Products` is unnecessary.

Comment: Good find, just removed the unnecessary join. Also, just FYI, depending on how you use this you may need to account for the same ingredients being used in multiple products which is not handled by this query.